# Append XML with XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, wcf

PurchaseList.xml

```
<purchaseList>
    <user id="13004">
      <books>
        <book isbn="1111707154" title="Music Potter 2" author="customer" price="10" currency="RM" />
      </books>
    </user>
</purchaseList>
```

WebService.cs

```
xDoc = XDocument.Load(serverPath + "PurchaseList.xml");
XElement xNewBook = (XElement)(from user in xDoc.Descendants("user")
                               where (String)user.Attribute("id") == userID
                               from books in user.Elements("books")
                               select user).Single();

XElement xPurchaseBook = new XElement("book",
    new XAttribute("isbn", xISBN),
    new XAttribute("title", xTitle),
    new XAttribute("author", "customer"),
    new XAttribute("price", xPrice),
    new XAttribute("currency", xCurrency));
xNewBook.Add(xPurchaseBook);
xNewBook.Save(localPath + "PurchaseList.xml");
```

Output :

```
<user id="13004">
    <books>
        <book isbn="1111707154" title="Music Potter 2" author="customer" price="10" currency="RM" />
    </books>
    <book isbn="1439056501" title="Harry Potter" author="customer" price="10" currency="RM" />
</user>
```

Expected output :

```
<purchaseList>
    <user id="13004">
      <books>
        <!-- Should append inside here -->
        <book isbn="1111707154" title="Music Potter 2" author="customer" price="10" currency="RM" />
        <book isbn="1439056501" title="Harry Potter" author="customer" price="10" currency="RM" />
      </books>
    </user>
</purchaseList>
```

As you can see, i wish to append the xml file using XElement, but output is ain't i expected, it even delete the  tag and append at the wrong position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `xNewBook.Add(xPurchaseBook);`

with `xNewBook.Element("books").Add(xPurchaseBook);`

You are `selecting user in LINQ query` and adding a new item in that. You need to get `books` element from the user and should add in that.

**OR**

You should get the `books` element and save the entire `xDoc` instead of `xNewBook`.

```
XElement xNewBook = (from user in xDoc.Descendants("user")
                      where (String)user.Attribute("id") == "13004"
                       select user.Element("books")).Single();
```

and save `xDoc` -

```
xDoc.Save(localPath + "PurchaseList.xml");
```